# Why does jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation throw an exception when sample buffer is NOT null?

Tags: ios, avcapture

In iOS, I am using code to capture from AVCaptureStillImageOutput thus:

[_captureStillOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection: _captureConnection
                                                             completionHandler: asyncCaptureCompletionHandler];

for simplicity to boil down my code, my asyncCaptureCompletionHandler block looks like this:

```
void(^asyncCaptureCompletionHandler)(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) = 
^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
    if (CMSampleBufferIsValid(imageDataSampleBuffer)) {
        NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];                                                                 
    }
}
```

I have been through all my code and cross referencing with stack overflow, and have not found any suggestion why a valid sample buffer would be captured without being a proper JPEG.

```
_captureStillOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
_captureStillOutput.outputSettings = 
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
         AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey,
         nil];

if ([session canAddOutput:_captureStillOutput]) {
            [session addOutput:_captureStillOutput];
}
```

There is supplemental info in the debugger:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:] - Not a jpeg sample buffer.'

Searches in google and stack overflow both for "Not a jpeg sample buffer" produced zero results.  I'm stuck. bah.

Answer (score 2):

This question is old but gold. I come from the future and can confirm that this still happens in 2015. I tried to go through the same steps to fix the issue, but to no avail. However, this question made me realize that the `CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer` behaves oddly when it's dealt with outside of the `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection`'s completion handler.

In a nutshell:

```
[self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:connection
                                                       completionHandler:^( CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error )
    {
        //call another method to handle the sample buffer causes weird behaviour
        //maybe the buffer is not being safely referenced by AVFoundation?
        [self handleBufferSomewhereElse:imageDataSampleBuffer]; //will behave strangely
        //even more so if you move to another thread
    }];
```

**Prefer doing this instead**:

```
[self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:connection
                                                       completionHandler:^( CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error )
    {
        //handle the buffer right here
        NSData *data = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer]; 
        //works better
    }];
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The next step for this solution was to log all the data reported in the debugger using:

```
po imageDataSampleBuffer
```

this always produced a lot of details while the exception was being thrown, lots of info on the sample buffer.  Then since posting this to SO, I commented out some code, then uncommented it, and now it is working.  Nothing changed in my code, however,  I did close some programs running on the mac.  Perhaps it was a development machine bug.  After this, I closed and reopened Xcode, and the exception has not been thrown.

Comment: Can confirm, a good ol' `rm -rf DerivedData/*` and restarting Xcode fixed this issue for me.

Comment: Actually, the issue reappeared but then went away when I closed iTunes. This is a pretty crazy one

Comment: Thanks for the note that it reappeared and then again disappeared.